# why it is unable to output characters the tweet of 2nd account with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

My environment is below:

Python Python 3.6.5

sqlite3 3.28.0

```
import tweepy
import sqlite3

# 認証キーの設定
consumer_key = \
    "XXXXXXXX"
consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXX"
access_token = "XXXXXXXX"
access_token_secret = "XXXXXXXX"

# OAuth認証
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbpath = 'db.sqlite3'
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbpath)
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()


db = Database()


def output_users_from_db():
    return db.c.execute('select name, comment from twitter_users')


def update_comment(name, comment='null'):
    db.c.execute("""update twitter_users set comment = ? where name = ?""", (comment, name))
    db.conn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    users_info_from_db = output_users_from_db()
    for i, user_info_on_db in enumerate(users_info_from_db):

        print(user_info_on_db[0])

        time_line = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user_info_on_db[0])
        for i, info in enumerate(time_line):
            # Below print functions can out put all of characters from twitter
            print(user_info_on_db[0]) # user account 
            print(info.text) # tweet
            break
```

Code above works. But if I write code below,

```
time_line = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user_info_on_db[0])
for i, info in enumerate(time_line):
    # Below print functions can out put all of characters from twitter
    print(user_info_on_db[0]) # user account 
    print(info.text) # tweet
    update_comment(user_info_on_db[0], comment=info.text)
    break
```

`print()` only works once, it cannot print 2nd account's tweet. How come when the code include `update_comment(user_info_on_db[0], comment=info.text)`, `print()` cannot output tweet of 2nd account?

Comment: Remove the `break` statement from the for loop. Inside a loop, when a `break` statement is encountered, the loop is exited.

Comment: If I remove ```break```, the code scrape all tweets of the account. Is there any way to get only the latest tweet?

Comment: I assume, that you have date column in your twiter_users table, so you could just change the query that fetches the results in output_users_from_db function to:

`select tu.name, tu.comment from twitter_users tu where tu.date_column_name = (select max(t.date_coumn_name) from twitter_users t where t.name = tu.name)`

This query will let you to find the latest tweet for each user. Let me know if that helps, so I could make it as an answer!

Comment: @NerijusLauzadis Thanks replied to me. I will use your way if I feel needs. By the way, now I want to know how to output the latest tweet of 2nd account very much right now.

Comment: Enumerate object lets you have an index on objects, so the hacky solution for that could be: `enum_list = list(enumerate(time_line) print(enum_list[1])`.

Comment: @NerijusLauzadis Your way gave me too much data. If I need more details of tweet, I can use it. But I need a simple way to show 2nd tweet.

Comment: So you get a tuple from enum_list[1], just change `print(enum_list[1])` to `print(enum_list[1][1].text` and it should give you the message of tweet.

Comment: @NerijusLauzadis ```enum_list = list(enumerate(time_line))```
        ```print(enum_list[1].text)``` caused ```"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'"```

Comment: `enum_list[1][1].text`

Comment: @NerijusLauzadis Thunks. But it can show the tweet of the first account. Could you tell me how to show the user names by enum_list?

Comment: `time_line = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user_info_on_db[0])` try to change to `time_line = api.user_timeline(screen_name=user_info_on_db[i])` where i should represent the index of account you want to see.

Comment: Still, the issue has been caused. The tweet of 2nd account (I input "SIROyoutuber") cannot ```print()```.

Comment: Anybody can help me?